# Connect to hadoop kerberos from kubernetes pod

Tags: hadoop, kubernetes

What ports needs to be exposed to be able to connect to kerberos/hadoop from within a pod? Deployment's service is created with ClusterIP.

Comment: Do you mean connecting from the outside into a pod? From within a pod you don't need to expose anything.

Comment: From within the pod to kerberos, I am getting below error from within the pod - ```bash-4.2$ kinit -kt ~/$(whoami).keytab $(whoami)@XYZ.COM
kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'XYZ.COM' while getting initial credentials``` I am able to run from the node, outside the pod.

Comment: Could you please provide deployment, clusterIP and other files? I would be able to reproduce it